# refactoring code to keep large objects/models in memory in iPython to be reused in python scripts

Tags: python, ipython

My script depends on loading lots of variables in a minute and uses them globally in many functions. Every time I call that script in iPython, it loads them again, taking time.

I tried to take these calls to load and populate functions out of that script, but then these global variables are not available to the functions in the script. 
It gives `NameError: name 'clf' is not defined` error message.

Is there a best way to refactor this code to keep these globals in memory and make the script use them? The script loads many variables like these, and uses them in other functions as globals.

`vectorizer_title, vectorizer_desc, clf, 
df_instance, vocab, all_tokens, df_dist_all, 
df_soc2class_proba, dict_p2s, 
dict_f2m, token_pattern, cleanup_pattern, 
excluded_words = load_data_and_model(lang)
dict_token2idx_all, dict_token2idx_instance, 
dist_array, token_dist_to_instance_min, 
dict_bigram_by_instance, denominate, 
similar_threshold = populate_data(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I had asked this question after trying 
`from depended_library import *`
it had not worked in iPython.
But used with python and used in a Flask Web API it works.

Importing library using the "from" statement executes also the codes out of functions in the depended_library in addition to defining functions.

(If someone explains the problem with iPython and suggest a solution, I shall select it as answer.)